# How to set two different adapter in a single recyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm showing a list of data. By default, I show data using `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter` as my list of data is large. I also have search options, when a user submits any query I searched the result in my `firebase realtime-database` in this case I used `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` for showing my result. By default, I'm getting expected result but when anything is searched I'm not getting any output. Is it possible to set a different adapter to a single recycler view? Here is my code

```java
private FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<BookLight, BookViewHolder> mAdapter;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BookLight,BookViewHolder> mAdapterNopage;
private static final String ALL_TYPE="all";


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid_grp);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        loadData(ALL_TYPE);

        return view;
    }

private void loadData(String queryBook){

        Query query;
        if(queryBook.equals(ALL_TYPE)){
          query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("GroupMembersBooks")
                    .child(groupDetails.getGroupID())
                    .child("books");
        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<BookLight, BookViewHolder>(options) {
      //other stuffs 
      recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      };
   }
    else{
            Log.e(TAG, "loadData: "+queryBook);
            query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("GroupMembersBooks")
                    .child(groupDetails.getGroupID())
                    .child("books")
                    .orderByChild("bookName")
                    .startAt(queryBook);
         mAdapterNopage = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BookLight, BookViewHolder>(options) {
     //other stuffs
     };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterNopage)
   }
 }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.group_timeline_menu,menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_book_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                loadData(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,menuInflater);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `swapAdapter`

```
recyclerView.swapAdapter(yourAdapter, false)
```

For more information about `swapAdapter`  refer here [swapAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#swapAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter,%20boolean))

Comment: thanks.  For default case I used `recyclerView.setAdapter()` and `recyclerView.swapAdapter()` for searched case. But still not getting any result.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `swapAdapter`, since you're using the same`ViewHolder` for both adapters.

From the documentation:

```
void swapAdapter (Adapter adapter, boolean removeAndRecycleExistingViews)
```

> Swaps the current adapter with the provided one. It is similar to setAdapter(Adapter) but assumes existing adapter and the new adapter uses the same RecyclerView.ViewHolder and does not clear the RecycledViewPool.

Note that it still calls `onAdapterChanged` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

it does all the magic

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23589273)

Comment: It does provide an answer, it can be used for swaping adapters.